# npx prisma db push command I try to push to MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, push, prisma, npx

I faced trouble when I use `npx prisma db push` command I try to push to MongoDB

this is error message

```
PS C:\Users\charith\Documents\GitHub\Full-Stack-Real-State-Website\server> npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "RealEstateWebsite" at "cluster0.ouvsfq4.mongodb.net"
Error: MongoDB error
Kind: An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (os error 10051), labels: {}
   0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
             at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:29
   1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:433
```

anyone know way to fix this or please tell why this happened?

Comment: I am facing the issue. Have you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was editing the network access setting by setting the IP address to 0.0.0.0/0

Also, ensure the password and username in the MongoDB URI match what you use to set up the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your network. I'm not sure why but using a vpn (I was using Proton but initializing a connection through Proton didn't solve the issue but using Warp VPN did). I don't have enough knowldge so i'm not going say more on this but if someone else can help explain this.

Resources:

- https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-econnrefused-and-replicasetnoprimary-errors/172477
- https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/14908